# Wanna unit-test a function, but constructor gives error

Tags: php

I am trying to unit test a function which is in an entity class, and it is stored in my DB by the use of a constructor. Each time I am trying to test this function it is giving me that error

> ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function App\Entity\Deal::__construct(), 0 passed in /var/www/html/casus/tests/dealsEntityFunctionsTest.php on line 10 and exactly 1 expected

It is obvious I think, but I am really new with unit testing and that stuff so I couldn't find the answer. Could you please help me?

My code is

```
class Deal
{
    private bool $isNewToday

    public function __construct($deal)
    {
        $this->isNewToday = $deal['is_new_today'];
    }

    public function getIsNewToday(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->isNewToday;
    }

    public function setIsNewToday(bool $isNewToday): self
    {
        $this->isNewToday = $isNewToday;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And my unit test is

```
class test extends TestCase
{
    public function testIsNewTodayIsTrue()
    {
        $deal = new Deal();
        $deal->setIsForSale(true);
        $this->assertTrue($deal->getIsForSale(), true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `new Deal();` requires a parameter `$deal`

Comment: when i put it in i get Undefined variable: deal

Comment: it has to be an array with a key named `is_new_today` like this `$deal = new Deal(['is_new_today' => true]);`

Comment: Well, you obviously need to define it first. Did you write that `Deal` class?

Comment: @Amer It's entirely up to you what you make the constructor expect, but if it expects something, you have to pass it. A unit test isn't any different from any other code that way.

Comment: The PHP manual has a section on [Function arguments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As brombeer suggested, new Deal entity requires parameter.
This parameter looks like an array, with key 'is_new_today'. So, sth like this below should help with constructor error.

```
class test extends TestCase
{
    public function testIsNewTodayIsTrue()
    {
        $deal = new Deal(['is_new_today' => true]);
        $deal->setIsForSale(true);
        $this->assertTrue($deal->getIsForSale(), true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much It is working, I just didn't know how to do it. The ['is_new_today' =>true] Gives an array value to is_new_today right?

Comment: Yes. To be more acurate,  ['is_new_today' =>true]  <- this is an array with key 'is_new_today' set to true.

Comment: Oh ok thank you

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Unit Testing, or Symfony, or any of the other details you mentioned. You've defined something with a mandatory parameter, and then aren't passing that parameter.

Just like any function, the parameters to a constructor are mandatory unless you provide a default. And if you write code that assumes the parameter will have a particular format, you need to provide a value that meets that assumption.

So either pass the parameter every time you create the object, with whatever format the constructor expects:

```
$deal = new Deal(['is_new_today' => false]);
```

... or make it optional, and decide what should happen if it's not passed:

```
class Deal
{
    private bool $isNewToday

    public function __construct(?array $deal = null)
    {
        if ( isset($deal) ) {
            $this->isNewToday = $deal['is_new_today'];
        }
        else {
            $this->isNewToday = false;
        } 
    }
}
```

Note that `$isNewToday` is defined as a non-nullable boolean, so you should always give it a value in the constructor, or an inline default, like `private bool $isNewToday = false;` Otherwise, you'll get "uninitialized value" errors if you try to read it. For that reason, the return type of `?bool` on `getIsNewToday()` doesn't make sense - it can't return null, because `$this->isNewToday` can never be bool.

Comment: I am sorry, but I thought that it is unit testing, because I am using unit testing with it, and I used Symfony because the website is made with symfony, but it was my mistake to mention it in the description/tags

Comment: @Amer Yes, sorry, I didn't mean that to sound like a criticism, I just wanted to emphasise that the same error would show up wherever you defined and used the class, so you don't think you need one solution in the unit test and a different solution somewhere else.

Comment: The ?bool is auto written when i created the entity using doctrine

Comment: No problem I understood it. All of your answers has really helped me thank you :D